# Dynamically change <textarea> depending on <select> in jinja2 / flask

Tags: python, html, flask, dynamic, jinja2

In my python file I have a dictionary 
`results = {'Key1':'Value1', 'Key2':'Value2'}`. I passed it in `return render_template('pages/queries.html', results=results)`

Now in html I have

```
    <select name="results">
        {% for key, value in results.items() %}
        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ key }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% for value in results.values() %}
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="results"> {{value}} </textarea>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is unfortunately displaying three textareas for some reason. **The desired result I want is someone selects a value from the dropdown (select html) and if they choose 'key2' then I want 'value2' to appear inside of textarea. If they choose 'key1' then dynamically I want textarea to update to 'value1'.** But this isn't happening and I've tried changing the locations of all the jinja codes and variations and haven't figured it out, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add onChange event handler and update text area accordingly.

```
    <select name="results" onchange="changeText(this);">
        {% for key, value in results.items() %}
        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="results" id="myTextArea"> {{results.values()[0]}} </textarea>
```

JS code for updating text area on `onChange` event.

```
function changeText(el) {
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = el.value;
}
```